# How to change cheese's countdown timer

Tags: settings, cheese, photo

How can I change the countdown time for photos in the Cheese Webcam Booth? Right now, it is 3. I'd like to set it to 6 or 10, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to change it. You can only disable it according to [Gnome Help](https://help.gnome.org/users/cheese/stable/index.html.en).